# Find a simple expression for the sum of in $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}n}{2^n}x^n$ its convergence interval

Tags: calculus

Is there a closed expression for
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}n}{2^n} x^n 
$$
I could find the convergence interval which is (-2,2) but I couldn’t  find a simple expression for the sum in that convergence interval.

Answer (score 2):

You can throw the $2$
and the $-1$
into the $x$ to get
$-\sum n(-x/2)^n
$.

See what happens
when you differentiate
$\sum x^n$
and go from there.